# Use laravel blade components from different folder

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade

For some reason, I put my Laravel blade components inside the App/Core/CoreComponents folder, so now I can't use these components like the old way:

```
<x-Core.CoreComponents.input />
```

And after searching I found a way by using this in AppServiceProvidor.php to make alias

```
// AppServiceProvidor.php in boot()
Blade::componentNamespace('CoreComponents', 'Core.CoreCoreComponents');

// use the components in blade.php
<x-CoreComponents::input />
```

but it does not work, so is there any way to do that?
and does it affect the performance? (note that I really want to put them inside App folder)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the document at https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#manually-registering-components, I think you have a typo:

```
<x-Core.CoreComponents::input />
```

instead of

```
<x-Core.CoreComponents.input />
```

And when register components namepsace, you have to use full namespace:

```
Blade::componentNamespace('App\\Core\\CoreComponents', 'Core.CoreCoreComponents');
```

Answer (score 0):

my web app does its job from the app/view. Anyways, I just read about the same topic on [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#manually-registering-components):

> components are automatically discovered within the **app/View/Components** directory and **resources/views/components** directory bu you can do this to your package's service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use App\Core\CoreComponents\InputComponent; //example

public function boot(): void
{
    Blade::component('input', InputComponent::class);    
//OR
    Blade::anonymousComponentPath(__DIR__.'/../Core/CoreComponents');
//OR the one you discovered already:
    Blade::componentNamespace('App\\Core\\CoreComponents', 'Core.CoreComponents'); //hint: <x-Core.CoreComponents::input>
}
```

Comment: it still not working and show this exception:
"Unable to locate a class or view for component [Core.CoreComponents::input].".

i tried to clear cache and views and composer dump-autoload.

and these what i used:
// this in create.blade.php
<x-Core.CoreComponents::input cols="6" type="text" id="name_en" name="name_en"  :model="$model" /> 

// and this in boot():
Blade::componentNamespace('App\\Core\\CoreComponents', 'Core.CoreComponents');

Comment: have you found the solution?